# Can all languages be ported to .NET?

Tags: .net, programming-languages

There are loads of Programming Languages. And many of them have their own .NET implementation. So my doubt is whether all languages can be ported to .NET or is there any requirement that a language need to have in order to be ported to .NET ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider .NET as a highly potent CPU, unless the language relies on a specific machine instruction there's nothing that stops you from implementing it in .NET (or Java or, or , or..).

Of course, some languages have rules about how to handle memory etc that can be hard to archieve transparent to .NET's basic ideas. It will probably be able to do it, but it might violate some basic principles how .NET code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if *all* language can be ported *as they are supposed to be used* ***with integration for other .NET langauges***.

That is, since the CLR framework/IL is turing-complete then any run-time (for any language?) can be written in it. However, this doesn't mean said run-time will be compatible with other .NET languages.

Consider a language that *requires* the use of a stack-less implementation and continuations, for instance where calls across the run-times are very problematic. Alternatively, consider a language like Haskell where (direct) integration with other type-systems and non-pure functions is less than ideal.

Happy coding.